# interference and molecular orbital theory

Tags: interference

why the energy of BMOs is lower and ABMOs is higher, rather we know that constructive interference take place in BMOs and as we know energy increases in constructive interference and vice versa for ABMOs:reference molecular orbital theory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interference does not play a role here. There is binding because both electrons are closer to the nuclei in the bonding orbital than in the original atomic orbitals. In the antibonding orbital the region between the atoms has a reduced electron density and therefor has higher energy than the original atomic orbitals.